# Drawing a custom picker wheel

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, user-interface

I'd like to create a wheel that will load some objects(different colors for instance) which the user can "spin" to see additional colors, something like this:

[image: Image sample here]

but I'm not sure where to begin. I'd like to be able to load up as many colors as I want, then queue/dequeue them as they move into and out of the visible view window. After some research, I'm getting the impression that using a `UIScrollView` is the way to achieve this? I'm going to dig some more into that option, but in the meantime it would be nice to know if that is the correct way to go or if that's totally wrong and there is some other/better approach.

Comment: If you want something that spins around like a wheel, then `UIScrollView` won't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's right, I do want it to spin like a wheel. Any suggestions on what will work? Do I just need to start with a custom UIView? UIScrollView sounded good, since it has most of what I need (the ability to queue/dequeue objects, scrolling with inertia). I guess I will need to build that functionality in myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out these [iDevBlogADay](http://www.idevblogaday.com) posts from August & September 2011:

- [Using CGAffineTransform for Circular Layout](http://rdsquared.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-cgaffinetransform-for-circular-layout-and-scrolling/)
- [Circular Layout and Scrolling, Part 2](http://rdsquared.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/circular-layout-and-scrolling-part-2/)

You may find them quite useful for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollView won't really buy you anything in this situation. It won't queue/dequeue things automatically (UITableView will though) and it only responses to horizontal & vertical scrolls. Out of the box, you can't rotate it around an axis.

There is really nothing in the UIKit to help you out, you will probably want to start of scratch with a UIView.

Use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer) (Dragging) and [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer) to keep track of when your user touches the rotating element. `UIRotatationGestureRecognizer` probably isn't what you want, because it requires the user to use two fingers.

Depending on how complex you are getting with this view, you may be able to get away with just doing:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(someRadian);
```

Calculate the rotation amount (in radians) based on how far x & y the user had drug. Depending on how fancy you want to get, 1 pixel x or y could get you a .1 radian rotation (I'm just guessing, you'll want to play around with it until you get the speed right). If you want to get really fancy and make your user actually arc their finger you'll want to use some trigonometry to translate that into a rotation amount.

If it is a swipe, calculate how far & long you want the view to rotate and wrap it in a UIView animation.

If you find this not working, you may need to go down to the CALayer, which is only slightly more complex:

```
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(someRadian, 0, 0, 1);
```

and to animate it you will need to create a CAAnimation:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotate.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
rotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:someRadian];
rotate.duration = 2.0; // seconds
[view.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:nil]; // "key" is optional
```

[This](http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Ask-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Rotating-an-iPhone-View-Around-a-Point) might give you more information

As for your adding/removing colors, by keeping track of how far the circle has rotated, you should be able to calculate which color swatches you want to see. But, if you are willing to make the concession to a limited number of colors, you could simply layout the UIView with all the colors in Interface Builder, add it to the root view with only the right hand corner visible, and then rotate it as described earlier and not have to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me lots to build on. Tried to mark it as useful, but guess I don't have enough reputation to do that yet...